# Validating a json object sent to the server

Tags: python, json

I have a simple json object sent to the server, and I want to validate it folowing this validation rule:

```
{
    "key": "k1",
    "name": "n3",
    "place": "p2",
        ...
}
```

the validation rule is that the value of the first element "key" should be one element of this list `["k1", "k2", "k3"]` and the same for name: `["n1", "n2", "n3"]` and so.

Is there a python library that make validation like this? I have tried out `jsonschema` but it is oriented types of data rather than traits.

Comment: how about just `if json["key"] in keys and json["name"] in names: ...`?

Comment: @msvalkon: Yes i thought of that in the bigining, but with an object that has more than 50 items...i let it as my last choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do something simple like this:

```
def get_valid_value_for_key(key):
    # return a list

def validate_json(json_dict):
    for key in json_dict.iterkeys():
        if not json_dict[key] in get_valid_value_for_key(key):
            return False # or raise an exception
    return True
```

Using a function can save you some typing, depending on how your valid values are defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
if json["key"] == "k1":

if json["name"] == "n1":

if json["place"] == "p1":
```

or create a dictionary

```
jsonDict = {"key": ["k1", "k2", "k3"], "name": ["n1", "n2", n3"], "place": ["p1", "p2", p3"]}
```

and use the json key to get the possible values for it.

So if I wanted to get all the values for key and loop through

```
possibleVals = jsonDict["key"]

for val in possibleVals:
    if val == jsonVal:
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [schema](https://github.com/halst/schema), a library for validating python data structures. You can define any function as a validator, so in your case you could just do something like `lambda x: x in acceptable_values`